# Returning values

Tags: c#

I have a method like below

```
public List<aspnet_Roles> GetAllRoles()
{
  var rolesList = _dbProfile.aspnet_Roles.ToList();
  return rolesList;
}
```

In this method first all the roles from database (LINQ to SQL) has been retrieved and assigned to a variable `rolesList` of type `var`.

I want to know if returning value directly is better instead of assigning it to other variables first and then returning it.

Is the below method is better than above version:

```
public List<aspnet_Roles> GetAllRoles()
        {
            return _dbProfile.aspnet_Roles.ToList();
        }
```

Will the above two methods compile in IL as same or second version is better? Second version doesn't have the unnecessary variable declaration.

Comment: I guess, creating a variable and assigning values is additional memory allocation. Instead if we return directly may be, i am not sure, this memory allocation to store list<aspnet_Roles> could be reduced. I don't know this is what i want to know. I guess this line _dbProfile.aspnet_Roles.ToList(); has already allocated to memory to store returned list. And again if we store it into another variable and then return it, i guess there is double memory allocation. I am not sure, plese guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confident (although I haven't checked) that these will compile to the same IL. The C# compiler is smart.

The advantage of the first version is that it makes it easier to breakpoint and check the value before returning.

The second version is more succinct, of course.

It's up to you which you prefer, there is no objective "better" here.

Comment: Is it possible to confirm that these will compile to same. If you could guide me, i will try it. Thanks for your comment BTW.

Comment: Well, you can try compiling them both and looking at them with [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

Comment: Is there any free reflector that i can use or a tool in visual studio that i can use to view the IL generated code.

Answer (score 6):

First method will help you with debugging. Right now, AFAIK, there is no way to watch return value of a method while debugging.

Other than that, there is no difference.